# Как используя эту форму поиска - сделать ее на своем сайте с выводом результатов?

Tags: html, поиск

**Необходимо на "другом" сайте сделать форму такую же и вывод результатов на "другом" с сайта изначального:**

#### Объекты недвижимости

Купить
    Арендовать

```
    </select>
</form>
<form name="search_property" class="search_right" action="http://multivilla.ru/properties/" method="post" >
    <select size="1" name="vid" onChange="this.form.action=this.value">
      <option value="http://multivilla.ru/properties/">Вид недвижимости</option>
      <option value="http://multivilla.ru/properties/appartments_2/" >Апартаменты</option>
<option value="http://multivilla.ru/properties/villas/" >Вилла</option>
<option value="http://multivilla.ru/properties/commercial/" >Коммерческая недвижимость</option>
<option value="http://multivilla.ru/properties/penthouses/" >Пентхаус</option>

    </select>
    <select size="1" name="district">
      <option value="">Месторасположение</option>
      <option value="Авсалалр" >Авсалалр</option>
<option value="Авсаллар" >Авсаллар</option>
<option value="Аланья" >Аланья</option>
<option value="Газипаша" >Газипаша</option>
<option value="Джикжилли" >Джикжилли</option>
<option value="Каргыджак" >Каргыджак</option>
<option value="Кестель" >Кестель</option>
<option value="Конаклы" >Конаклы</option>
<option value="Махмутлар" >Махмутлар</option>
<option value="Оба" >Оба</option>
<option value="Тосмур" >Тосмур</option>

    </select>
    <input name="price_from" type="text" value="" placeholder="Цена от">
    <input name="price_to" type="text" value="" placeholder="Цена от">
    <input name="rooms" type="text" value="" placeholder="Комнат от">
    <input name="bathrooms" type="text" value="" placeholder="Ванных от">
    <select size="1" name="currency">
      <option value="Евро" >Евро</option>
<option value="Доллары" >Доллары</option>
<option value="Рубли" >Рубли</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>

<form name="search_rent_property" class="search_right" action="http://multivilla.ru/arenda/" method="post"  style="display:none">
    <input name="r_price_from" type="text" value="" placeholder="Цена в день от, Евро">
    <input name="r_price_to" type="text" value="" placeholder="Цена в день до, Евро">
    <select size="1" name="planning">
      <option value="">Планировка</option>
      <option value="0+1" >0+1</option>
<option value="1+1" >1+1</option>
<option value="2+1" >2+1</option>
<option value="4+1" >4+1</option>

    </select>
    <input name="r_sleep" type="text" value="" placeholder="Спальных мест">
    <input name="r_chekin" type="text" value="" placeholder="Дата заезда" id="r_chekin" onClick="showCalendar24(this)">
    <input name="r_chekout" type="text" value="" placeholder="Дата выезда" id="r_chekout" onClick="showCalendar24(this)">
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Comment: Поправьте код, он разлетелся на блоки...

Comment: Подправила за Вас...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Поясните, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Мой внутренний телепат подсказывает, что у автора сейчас статический сайт с одними лишь html-страничками и ему надо учиться писать веб-приложения (или осваивать какую-то CMS)

Comment: Это сайт изначальный.

Comment: Необходимо на "другом" сайте сделать форму такую же и вывод результатов на "другом" с сайта изначального:)

Comment: С движками знаком, но вопрос не в движках, а в HTML коде. Как его подправить:))

Comment: Пробовал вставить GET и т.д. все равно выдает именно родной (изначальный) сайт.